# Create variable only if function argument is missing

Tags: r

I need to write a function that takes dataframe columns as arguments, and will add new variables to the dataframe if any of these are missing, such as going from

```
    foo bar
1    1   1
2    2   2
3    3   3
4    4   4
5    5   5
6    6   6
7    7   7
8    8   8
9    9   9
10  10  10
```

to:

```
   foo bar  arg3
1    1   1 NA
2    2   2 NA
3    3   3 NA
4    4   4 NA
5    5   5 NA
6    6   6 NA
7    7   7 NA
8    8   8 NA
9    9   9 NA
10  10  10 NA
```

. So far, I have this example:

```
df <- data.frame(foo = 1:10, bar = 1:10)

CheckData <- function(data, arg1 = NULL, arg2 = NULL, arg3 = NULL) {

  list_args <- list(arg1, arg2, arg3)

  # lapply(list_args, function(x) if(is.null(x)) data[[x]] <<- NA)
  # lapply(list_args, function(x) if(is.null(x)) data$x <<- NA)

  return(data)

}

CheckData(df, arg1 = 'foo', arg2 = 'bar')
```

So, I pass the function a dataframe with 2 columns, foo & bar, which allows arg3 to be `NULL`, the default value. In the 2 commented out lines, we have 2 options -

1. the first would ideally see that, since `arg3` in `list_args` is `NULL`, a new variable `data[[arg3]]` should be created & populated with `NA`s. However, this doesn't work, and I wonder if perhaps some non-standard evaluation would help here, so that it sees this not as a `NULL` object but as a name/string.
2. the second works in this way, but creates a variable called `df$x`, not `df$arg3`.

I could explicitly do this one by one, such as

```
CheckData <- function(data, arg1 = NULL, arg2 = NULL, arg3 = NULL) {

  if(is.null(arg1)) data$arg1 <- NA
  if(is.null(arg2)) data$arg2 <- NA
  if(is.null(arg3)) data$arg3 <- NA      

  return(data)

}

CheckData(df, arg1 = 'foo', arg2 = 'bar')
```

but this would be inelegant and require prior knowledge of all possible variables, which isn't realistic for my needs.

This seems like it should be a fairly straight-forward problem for advanced R programmers, but I'm blocked and can't find a solution despite some hours of searching and trial and error. Many thanks for any help

Comment: After re-reading your question I’m not entirely sure what you want to accomplish — do you want to fill the newly added columns with `NA` or with other, given values?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I would want to do (NAs for now). I want to end up with a standardised dataframe with all required variables/columns present in order for some standardised analyses to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution using some inherent functionality within the `plyr` package and using `assign` instead of the assignment operator (`<-`), which allows me to have the names of the arguments mapped to the variables, as below:

```
library(magrittr)
dat <- data.frame(foo = 1:10, bar = letters[1:10])

CheckData <- function(data, arg1 = NULL, arg2 = NULL, arg3 = NULL, arg4 = NULL) {

  # create dataframe of missing/unmatched arguments
  list_args <- 
    list(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) %>% 
    setNames(c('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4')) %>% 
    plyr::ldply(function(x) if(is.null(x)) NA)

  # create new variables based on these missing arguments; map the arguments to these variables
  for(i in list_args[[1]]) {data[[i]] <- NA; assign(i, i)}

  return(data)

}

tmp <- CheckData(dat, arg1 = 'foo', arg2 = 'bar')
```

which gives the following dataframe, which is exactly what I wanted:

```
   foo bar arg3 arg4
1    1   a   NA   NA
2    2   b   NA   NA
3    3   c   NA   NA
4    4   d   NA   NA
5    5   e   NA   NA
6    6   f   NA   NA
7    7   g   NA   NA
8    8   h   NA   NA
9    9   i   NA   NA
10  10   j   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

The following does what you want:

```
CheckArgs = function (df, ...) {
    args = list(...)
    for (arg in names(args)) {
        if (! arg %in% names(df))
            df[[arg]] = args[[arg]]
    }

    df
}
```

Alternatively, the following does the same, but without the loop:

```
CheckArgs = function (df, ...) {
    args = list(...)
    missing = ! names(args) %in% names(df)
    df[names(args)[missing]] = args[missing]
    df
}
```

Usage:

```
df = CheckArgs(df, a = NA, b = NA, c = NA)
```

If you only ever want to fill the vector with `NA`s, then a better solution would be to have a function that allows you just to specify the required names:

```
df = CheckArgs(df, c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

… or something along these lines. This can of course easily be done in much the same way:

```
CheckArgs = function (df, required_names) {
    missing = ! required_names %in% names(df)
    df[required_names[missing]] = NA
    df
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Konrad. It doesn't quite work how I would need it however - when calling the function, there will be some mapping of variables as specified by the caller - e.g. in a real example where a dataframe has 2 variables `weight` & `height`: `CheckArgs(weightVar = 'weight', heightVar = 'height')`. Let's say the dataframe also needs an age variable (`ageVar`), which if present could be matched by `ageVar = 'age'` but if absent, doesn't need to be specified in the function call but the function will automatically create a new variable `ageVar` and fill it with NA. Is that any clearer?